# Developer Console checkpoint in Salesforce Production

Tags: developer-console, production, checkpoint

Is it possible to use checkpoint feature for apex classes and triggers directly in production instance?

I could not find any details about that [here](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_checkpoints_setting.htm&language=en_US) in Salesforce documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as you have view all data. The easiest way to figure this out is to just try it in production, but it does give you a little more info in the [API docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/api_tooling.pdf). In the API, checkpoint is called ApexExecutionOverlayResult.

"When you are troubleshooting a runtime issue, you often want to find out more about the state of a variable or the state of the database, or create a specific condition to test your code. Use ApexExecutionOverlayAction to overlay a diagnostic output on an Apex class or trigger without compromising production code."

Comment: The reason I asked is because we cannot edit classes in production. So how can we set the checkpoints? Currently, I don't have access to any production instance. Wanted to hear from others for now.

Comment: You mean, we can use only the tooling api and not developer console checkpoints feature for production instance?

Comment: Checkpoints don't alter anything. They just take a snapshot so they are safe to use in production. The problem before was developers had to deploy system.debug statements to production to see what was going on. Now, you can just set the checkpoint to see what is going on. You need view all data though, since the information in the checkpoint may be sensitive. You can use the developer console in production too to view logs and checkpoints, run queries, etc, but you cannot modify code.